# Find if strings in an array share a substring and trim it out

Tags: php

I have an array of strings, let's say they're filenames, which look something like this

```
$filenames = [
    "Index",
    "ACME Corp - Services",
    "Products - ACME Corp",
    "Contact Us - ACME Corp",
    "History - ACME Corp - The greatest producer of ACME widgets!"
];
```

Let's say I have no control over these.

How would I approach writing an algorithm that would

- figure out that `ACME Corp` is a common substring, *but one that doesn't appear in all the strings*
- trim `ACME Corp` out of the filenames (it can leave behind the dashes and spaces)

I can't wrap my head around the first step - how do I iterate through this array and find the shared substring?

**Update:** Just to address some of the comments, it would have word boundary and be case insensitive, so `ACME Corp` and `acme corp` would be acceptable matches, but anything matching that pattern within a word would not be.

Comment: Are you looking to _only_ find the longest common substring, or every common substring, or just any common substring?

Comment: Only the longest common substring, but one that doesn't necessarily appear in all the strings.

Comment: You would essentially have to one at a time break each string into a substring of a certain length and compare to all other strings.

Comment: Does it have _word_ boundary like in your example (`ACME Corp` = 2 words) or does it have to work with substrings within words?

Comment: This will be VERY computationally expensive.

Comment: along the same lines as hpd is asking, does whitespace and/or case matter? i.e. would `ACME corp` be the same if it had two spaces in it or was lower case?

Comment: Check out the Wikipedia entry on [longest common substring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem). There are some goodies in the references and external links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing what problem you're trying to solve this a tough one. You could explode each string in the array by space and capture the amount of occurrences the string appears in the array but this doesn't account for phrases. A search engine is the appropriate solution but without knowing what term or phrase you're looking for it won't help you much.

Explode rough idea:

```
$words = array();
foreach ($stringArr as $str) {
    $parts = explode(" ", $str);
    foreach ($parts as $word) {
        $words[$word] += 1;
    }
}
```